# Republishing is killing IIS

Tags: publishing, iis

Recently trying to move content from production down to my development environment. So, I backed up and restored the Master DB, then tried to republish everything. Mostly this ws very slow but OK. But the Media Library is killing IIS. I get the following error:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: TargetInvocationException 
Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MethodCommandProcessor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MethodCommand.Execute(CommandContext context)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.Dispatch(String command)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

The publishing process was unexpectedly interrupted.
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm.CheckStatus()
```

Which led me to this:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/908303

Which suggests increasing Publishing.TimeBeforeStatusExpires  to 10 minutes, but this seemed to have no effect. How do I get around this?

Comment: as far I see the default value is 2 hours. Can you increase the value to 10 hours not decrease to 10 minutes.

Comment: if the issue continues, you can think of implementing Sitecore Publishing Service.

Comment: If you really struggle and don't actually need things to be published, you should consider just switching to using the master database directly. There is a `LiveMode.config` example you can use as a start.

Comment: Another option if you are really struggling but need it in web, might be to back up and restore the target (web) database from production. Note that there might be a performance impact on the live site when doing this.

Comment: @Jeroen Im leaning towards this

Comment: You may need to perform some cleanup after you restored the master db. Cleanup on the event queues, properties table.